# How to send a form with appended el via js?

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress

I have a form which i then send via php:

```
<form action="" id="primaryPostForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="postContent">Content of your post</label>
  <textarea name="postContent[]" class="postContent form-control" style="height: 400px"><?php echo $c; ?></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-dark" id="addContent">Aggiungi</button>
</form>
```

I also have a js script to add a second textarea:

```
var newTextArea = "<label for='postContent'>Content of your post</label><textarea name='postContent[]' class='postContent form-control' style='height: 400px;'></textarea>";
$("#addContent").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(newTextArea ).insertBefore(this);
});
```

I then process the form with post:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  foreach($_POST['postContent'] as $value) {
     add_post_meta ( $post_id, 'content', $value );
  }...
```

But it's only sending the latest textarea I add.

This is the var_dump I get:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "
First one

" [1]=> string(20) "
New added one

" } array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "
First one

" [1]=> string(20) "
New added one

" }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249425/discussion-on-question-by-rob-m-how-to-send-a-form-with-appended-el-via-js).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to few comments I realised the issue was with the php code:

When sending the form I did:

```
foreach($_POST['postContent'] as $value) {
  delete_post_meta ( $post_id, 'content' );
  add_post_meta ( $post_id, 'content', $value );
}
```

That is because I wanted to clear all the meta fields before to send the new updated ones, yet the use of `delete_post_meta ( $post_id, 'content' );` within the loop was removing what's added and leaving the latest one only.

Therefore the working code is:

```
delete_post_meta ( $post_id, 'content' );
foreach($_POST['postContent'] as $value) {
  add_post_meta ( $post_id, 'content', $value );
}
```

This wasn't included in the original code on the question

```
delete_post_meta ( $post_id, 'content' );
```

as I didn't believe that was the issue. That was the mistake. Works now.

Comment: Ah...so we didn't actually have a [mre] of the issue, which won't have helped our understanding. I'm glad you solved it and hopefully learned something in the process :-)

Comment: @ADyson yes exactly, but the main thing was me not believing the issue was with the php as it was working using other methods, so i didn't think to include it at all. I was wrong. Thanks tho, you've helped me to understand.